# Build error : qemu-arm: command not found

Tags: qemu

I get the following eror while building on linux .

> /bin/sh: qemu-arm: command not found
>   /bin/sh: qemu-aarch64 command not found

Can anybody help me how to resolve this error ?

Comment: Please provide your code, or some more information.

Comment: provide information on how you have installed? what is the host machine? what are the steps you have followed to install  qemu?

Answer (score 2):

because you haven't installed the qemu package. Which linux release have you used?RHEL/Debian series?

if RHEL series, you can download via yum:

```
yum install qemu-system-arm qemu
```

if Debian, you can download via apt:

```
apt install qemu-system-arm qemu
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to install `qemu-user` package to run the user level emulation `qemu-arm`

```
apt-get install qemu-user
```

Note, that the `qemu-system-arm` package does not have `qemu-arm` command. Instead to do a system level emulation you need to run `qemu-system-arm` and specify the machine that you need as a parameter. See this command for more:

```
qemu-system-arm -machine help
```